Mostrar PDF de múltiples paginas con jsPDF
No he usado esta librería antes así que estoy teniendo algunos problemas.
Necesito mostrar un xml en un PDF y funciona solo que no cabe del todo en 1 sola pagina, puedo mostrar 2 paginas solo que el xml en la segunda pagina vuelve a mostrarse desde el inicio y lo que necesito es que allí se muestre la parte faltante obviamente.
Me encontre este código por allí
function createPdfFromText(text) {
  const doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.setFont('courier', 'normal');
  doc.setFontSize(10);

  doc.text(text, 10, 5);
  const pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
  let y = 500; // Height position of new content

  if (y >= pageHeight) {
    doc.addPage();
    y = 0; // Restart height position
  }
  //doc.text(text, 10, 5);

  doc.save('FEXML.pdf');
}


Hasta donde sé, esta libreria no cuenta con una funcion nativa para esta tarea, por lo que tendrás que dividir el texto tu mismo. Intenta probar este codigo:


function createPdfFromText(text) {
  const doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.setFont('courier', 'normal');
  doc.setFontSize(10);

  const margin = 10; 
  const maxWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width - 2 * margin; 
  const lineHeight = 7; 
  let y = 10; 

  
  const lines = doc.splitTextToSize(text, maxWidth);

  lines.forEach((line) => {
    
    if (y > doc.internal.pageSize.height - 10) { 
      doc.addPage();
      y = 10; 
    }

    doc.text(line, margin, y);
    y += lineHeight; 
  });

  doc.save('FEXML.pdf');
}




Me funciono, gracias.
